# Count and transfer to new sheet VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need to find the number of students for each studyboard, I have all of the numbers for each studyboard in column H so my code right now just counts how many time each number occur. I was wondering if there was an easier way to do this because as you can see my code is very long. Also i need to transfer the number of students to a new sheet called statistics. 
Hope someone can help

```
Sub countstudents()
Range("V2") = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("H2:H18288"), "1")
Range("V7") = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("H2:H18288"), "22")
Range("V8") = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("H2:H18288"), "23")
Range("V9") = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("H2:H18288"), "24")
Range("V10") = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("H2:H18288"), "25")
Range("V11") = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("H2:H18288"), "26")
Range("V12") = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("H2:H18288"), "28")
Range("V13") = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("H2:H18288"), "29")
Range("V14") = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("H2:H18288"), "31")
Range("V15") = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("H2:H18288"), "32")
Range("V16") = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("H2:H18288"), "33")
Range("V17") = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("H2:H18288"), "34")
Range("V18") = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("H2:H18288"), "35")
Range("V19") = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("H2:H18288"), "36")
Range("V20") = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("H2:H18288"), "41")
Range("V21") = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("H2:H18288"), "81")
Range("V22") = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("H2:H18288"), "121")
Range("V23") = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("H2:H18288"), "122")
Range("V24") = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("H2:H18288"), "163")
Range("V25") = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("H2:H18288"), "164")
Range("V26") = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("H2:H18288"), "183")
Range("V27") = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("H2:H18288"), "184")
Range("V28") = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("H2:H18288"), "185")
Range("V29") = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("H2:H18288"), "")
```

Comment: Use a pivot table.

Comment: You could use an array with 2 columns, and then loop through it. That would minimise the lines of code you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

First we build a 2d array containing all your row numbers from the range formula, and the criteria for your `Countif()`

The we itterate over that array to fill the worksheet cells. Important to note is that it is wise to explicitly reference the workbook and the worksheet in which this needs to be pasted. So for example `Workbooks("book1.xlsx").worksheets("sheet1").Range() =`

```
Sub countstudents()
Dim i as long
Dim j as long
dim k as long
Dim arr(1 to 24, 1 to 2) as string
    arr(1, 1) = 2
    arr(1, 2) = 1
    arr(24, 1) = 29
    arr(24, 2) = ""
    For i is 2 to 23
      For j is 1 to 2
         If j = 1 then 
            arr1(i,j) = 5 + i 'starts at 7 and goes till 28
         Else 
            arr1(i,j) = 20 + i 'starts at 22 and goes till 43
         End if
      next j
    next i 

For k = 1 to ubound(arr)
    Range("v"&arr(k,1)) = application.worksheetfunction.countif(Range("H2:H18288"), arr(k,2))
next k
end sub
```

Comment: hmmm just noticed that your criteria in the `Countif()`function isn't as regular as I thought, it stops being regular at the value of 26. Hence my approach will go faulty there. That could be solved by adding a bunch of IF statements, but then you would end up with a similar lengthy code as you started with, hence beating the point.